# bash; content of the file does not contain more than

Tags: bash

i am looking for a way to check in bash if there is more than the following statement in a log file.
The beginning is the time, this should be ignored during the check.

```
10:56:28.035 [info] Migrations already up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **grep -v** to remove the pattern that is always there and you can use the option **-c** of the grep command to count the remaining lines :

let's assume "file" contains :

```
10:56:28.035 [info] Migrations already up
```

You can filter this line (with a regexp to replace the time and its variations) :

```
grep -v -c '^[0-9.:]* \[info\] Migrations already up$' file
```

if this command returns 0 it means that there is 0 lines other than the one above, so your file is okay

Otherwise, the command will return the number of additional lines.

Comment: Piping `grep` to `wc -l` is basically always unnecessary; that's why we have `grep -c`.  Comparing the result to zero is another antipattern; simply use `grep -q`.  See also [useless use of `wc`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc)

Comment: (Looks like Dreamhost is having issues. Check back later, or try https://web.archive.org/web/20210521202845/http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#wc)

Comment: but i want to find out if there is more than just this line in the file, that doesn't work with `grep -q`? @tripleee

Comment: `grep -q -v '^that-line$'` will return success if there are lines other than `that-line`. (More conveniently `grep -q -v -x 'that-line'`; maybe pepper with `-F` if you have a static string instead of a regex.)

Comment: @triplee, thanks for the reminder, I've edited the post to replace the **| wc -l** with the option **-c**

Comment: That's still an antipattern, as discussed above; but definitely an improvement.

Comment: If you don't want to use an antipattern **-v**, but you still want to know if there are more lines than the 'normal lines' in the file, you'll have to compare the number of 'normal lines' returned by your 'grep' with the total number of lines in the file, won't you?

Comment: The `-c` option is the antipattern, when you only care whether there were any matches or not. Then `grep -q` sets its exit code, and you should examine that (true means there were matches, false means there weren't).